# jQuery plugin for dynamically adding input fields with plus/minus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a web app and thought that surely something like this must exist, specifically as a jQuery or bootstrap plugin.

I'm trying to allow the user to populate a dynamic html list sort of like this quick and dirty fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2hjvaa6n/

Code here:

```
<span style="color: red; font-size: 36px; margin: 0px 10px 0px 35px;">-</span>
<label>Item Name</label>
<input type="text"/>
&nbsp;
<label>Item Price</label>
<input type="text"/>
<br/>
<span style="color: green; font-size: 36px;">+</span>
<span style="color: red; font-size: 36px; margin: 0px 10px;">-</span>
<label>Item Name</label>
<input type="text"/>
&nbsp;
<label>Item Price</label>
<input type="text"/>
```

Very simple, but I hope it communicates what I'm looking for.  Just a plus and minus button where you can keep adding/removing instances of the two text boxes, so you can make an array of inputs. I know how to build this myself, but if there's already a plugin out there, it would be better and cleaner than anything I could throw together. I've searched quite a bit, but haven't found anything.

Comment: maybe something like this? http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Dynamically-Add-Remove-Html-Elements-with-jQuery-Duplicate-Plugin.html

Comment: you should use some sort of template engine like https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template but probably it's best to use knockout.js

Comment: well sometimes the 'better and cleaner' way of doing things like this comes with building your own and making it as generic as possible. That is because plugins usually wrap the functionality with the rest of their code making it more complicated than it needs to be, although achieving what you're aiming for in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monxas' comment with [JQuery Duplicate](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Dynamically-Add-Remove-Html-Elements-with-jQuery-Duplicate-Plugin.html) was probably the closest to what I was looking for, so I will use it.  It just seems like I run into this a lot with multiple phone numbers, addresses, names, user defined fields, and other one-to-many relationships. One would almost think there should be a browser supported 'array' input type.

Thanks for the advice everyone.